# How to extract specific rows based on row number from a file

Tags: shell, extract, file-handling

I am working on a RNA-Seq data set consisting of around 24000 rows (genes) and 1100 columns (samples), which is tab separated. For the analysis, I need to choose a specific gene set. It would be very helpful if there is a method to extract rows based on row number? It would be easier that way for me rather than with the gene names.

Below is an example of the data (4X4) -

> gene    Sample1    Sample2    Sample3
>
> A1BG       5658    5897      6064
>
> AURKA    3656    3484      3415
>
> AURKB    9479    10542    9895

From this, say for example, I want row 1, 3 and4, without a specific pattern

I have also asked on [biostars.org](https://www.biostars.org/p/315175/).

Comment: You mean like `sed -n -e 1p -e 3,4p filename`? (this assumes your data really doesn't contain blank-lines)

Comment: Yes! This solution is perfect, but I have a question. Is there any other way to do it, because I need to select 230 rows that are shuffled across 24000 rows. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Dear Halfer, thank you for the edit. Although, I added 'urgent' not to get a faster answer, but to justify the reason for putting it up on two blogs. I'll anyway refrain from using it in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a for-loop to build the `sed` options like below

```
var=-n
for i in 1 3,4 # Put your space separated ranges here
do
 var="${var} -e ${i}p"
done
sed $var filename
```

<sup>**Note:** In any case the requirement mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364556/how-to-extract-specific-rows-based-on-row-number-from-a-file/50366110#comment87748500_50364556) would still be pain as it involves too much typing.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a file, or a program that generates a list of the line numbers you want, you could edit that with `sed` to make it into a script that prints those lines and passes it to a second invocation of `sed`.

In concrete terms, say you have a file called `lines` that says which lines you want (or it could equally be a program that generates the lines on its `stdout`):

```
1
3
4
```

You can make that into a `sed` script like this:

```
sed 's/$/p/' lines
1p
3p
4p
```

Now you can pass that to another `sed` as the commands to execute:

```
sed -n -f <(sed 's/$/p/' lines) FileYouWantLinesFrom
```

This has the advantage of being independent of the maximum length of arguments you can pass to a script because the `sed` commands are in a pseudo-file, i.e. not passed as arguments.

---

If you don't like/use `bash` and *process substitution*, you can do the same like this:

```
sed 's/$/p/' lines | sed -n -f /dev/stdin FileYouWantLinesFrom
```

Comment: Nice note on `maximum length of arguments`.